# Using mysql to save user accounts

Tags: mysql

I am making an app and trying to save user data in a mysql db.
I've been searching on the web and found that maximum columns per table is upto 1000 when using innoDB.
1000 seems quite small to me and I'm trying to figure out how to manage the accounts efficiently... can someone help me out

Comment: What you did so far?

Comment: @phpexpert nothing much with DB but just the app... Maybe I can put all the values into some strings with identifiers included...

Comment: @phpexpert I have to save hundreds of numbers but the number of numbers varies within users.. I thought I have to save them as int forms but putting them together into strings might do...

Comment: Why you want columns more than 1000 in single table? It will be very difficult to manage.

Comment: @phpexpert There are some properties the user can make and select... The properties can be made by the user so I thought it would be a good idea to put them together with the user accounts